# What is the difference between "to rally the defense/support" and "to rally to the defense/support"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

I'd like to understand when to use "*to rally + noun*" and when to use "*to rally **to** + noun*".
For this purpose, I prepared the following examples:

---

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rally_2):
**(1)** *The country hastily rallied its defences*.
my variant:
**(2)** *The country hastily rallied **to** its defences*.
What's the difference between them?

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rally_2) (from the section "Extra Examples"):
**(3)** *BBC leaders rallied **to** his defence*.
my variant:
**(4)** *BBC leaders rallied his defence*.
What's the difference between them?

---

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rally_2):
**(5)** *Many national newspapers rallied **to** his support*.
my variant:
**(6)** *Many national newspapers rallied his support*.
What's the difference between them?

[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rally):
**(7)** *an attempt to rally support for the party*
my variant:
**(8)** *an attempt to rally **to** support for the party*
What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Rally" is a transitive/intransitive verb: it can either have a direct object or not. In your examples, the versions **without the preposition "to"** are **transitive**, while the versions **with the preposition "to"** are **intransitive**.  This changes the meaning significantly!

The [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rally) gives the relevant definitions as "to muster for a common purpose [or] to arouse for action" (transitive), and "to come together again to renew an effort [or] to join in a common cause" (intransitive).

This means that in general, **one or the other** of these usages will be correct in any given context. Some sentences syntactically could take either, but the results won't be interchangeable: they will have different meanings.

---

**So, for your examples:**

**1.** "The country hastily rallied its defenses." ***Correct** - the meaning is that the country organized its defenses.*
**2.** "The country hastily rallied **to** its defenses." ***Possibly correct, but less likely** - the meaning is that the country organized **around** its defenses.*

**3.** "BBC leaders rallied **to** his defense." ***Correct** - this means that BBC's leaders came together to support him.*
**4.** "BBC leaders rallied his defense." ***Technically correct, but unlikely meaning** - this would imply that "his defense" is an actual team of some kind (legal, maybe?) instead of just referring to moral support or public endorsement of [him]. It would also imply that this team was failing in its efforts until the BBC leaders stepped in!*

**5.** vs. **6.** has the same distinction as **3.** vs **4.**

**7.** "An attempt to rally support for the party" ***Correct** - refers to an attempt to recruit people, or at least their time and investment, for the party.*
**8.** "An attempt to rally **to** support for the party" ***Unlikely** - refers to a (presumed unsuccessful?) attempt for people to come together around some not-well-defined place, event or ideal which supports the party.*

Comment: I don't understand why "_to rally support_" in "_an attempt to rally support for the party_" means "to recruit people, time and investment". You say "_his defense_" in "_BBC leaders rallied his defense_" is a team. Therefore, "_support_" in "_an attempt to rally support for the party_" is supposed to be a team too. Why is it not so? Thanks.

Comment: @Lovii I was interpreting "defense" in 4. as definition 4a here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defense and not as definition 1a, which would normally be more common. The reason for that is that otherwise "defense" would be an abstract concept, which isn't something one can "muster for a common purpose or arouse for action." For your example 7., "support" can refer to people (as they can be "mustered for a common purpose") or by extension, to their involvement [time and investment] which is the "action" in "arouse for action."

Comment: More generally, if you're using the *transitive* meaning of "rally," the direct object should normally be a concrete noun and not an abstract noun.

Comment: I thought "to rally support for the party" could only mean "to unite those people who already support the party for some time" but you say it means "to recruit the people" who might not support the party before. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Lovii If it were, "to rally **the** support for the party," then it would have to refer to people who already support the party. Without the definite article, it could mean a "call to action" for people who already support the party, **or** a "muster" of people who weren't previously involved.

Comment: Thank you. Also I don't quite understand your explanation of "_an attempt to rally **to** support for the party_". If we say it as in (3), I mean: "_BBC leaders rallied **to** support for the party_" - is this variant now correct as (3)?

Comment: @Loviii I think TimR has done a better job of explaining the difference between the transitive and intransitive usages of "rally" in his new answer. Maybe that will answer your question?

Comment: To explore each sentence individually (as you did) is much more difficult than that thing which is said in the other two answers. Your answer is the only that has a value for me (I don't blame the other posters. Perhaps I badly formulate what I want).

Comment: At this moment there remains one thing in your answer I don't understand: why is "_BBC leaders rallied to his defense_" correct, whereas "_an attempt to rally to support for the party_" is unlikely? Is it all about "an attempt"? That is, if we say "_rally to support for the party_" or "_BBC leaders rallied to support for the party_", then did it become "likely" now? Because to me: "_BBC leaders rallied to his defense_" and "_BBC leaders rallied to support for the party_" have the same structure and, therefore, either both are good or both are bad. Could you try to explain it please?

Comment: @Loviii The reason I believe that particular example is unlikely is unrelated to the distinction between it being a successful or unsuccessful attempt. It's actually because of how vague the word "support" is in that context, compared to "defense." "Rallied to his defense" is OK because "to his defense," when used that way, is just another way of expressing *purpose* - it has the same meaning as "rallied *to defend him*." If you just swapped out the word "defense" for "support" while changing nothing else, it would also still be idiomatic: "rallied to his support" is a valid alternative (ctd.)

Comment: to "rallied *to support him*."

Comment: But, what makes "rallied to *support for the party*" **un-idiomatic** is the extra prepositional phrase. This forces "support" to represent an actual 'thing,' instead of just a different way of expressing purpose. But, what kind of thing is it? It's unclear, and this makes the entire sentence awkward. In contrast, "rallied to support the party" would be both clear and valid.

Comment: @Loviii Come to think of it, it seems to really boil down to the distinction between the **preposition "to"** and the **infinitive-marker "to"**. "Rally **to** support **for** the party" sets the reader up to *expect* the word "to" to be the infinitive marker, but then the preposition "for" forces "to" to also be a preposition. I think this is what's called a "garden-path sentence," where the reader is made to interpret an ambiguous construction one way, realize they're wrong, and then go back and re-interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

If A rallies **to** B's support then it is A who are directly supplying the support.

For example "Many national newspapers rallied **to** his support." would imply that they published favourable articles or attacked his opponents in print.
If "Many national newspapers rallied his support." It is more likely that they arranged / encouraged /  financed others to help / support him, for example by paying his legal costs.
This is not a hard and fast difference and there may well be overlapping actions. but in general **to** implies direct support, and without **to** it implies indirect support.

Answer (score 1):

**rally** has both transitive and intransitive uses.

**To rally someone** <sup>direct object, transitive</sup> means to encourage or rouse them to take  united action towards some goal.

> Activists rallied the community in an attempt to have the new airport runway flight path diverted so that planes taking off and landing would follow the river instead of flying at low altitudes directly over their homes.

**To rally**  <sup>intransitive</sup> followed by a complement expressing an end, means to unite in order to achieve the end.

> The community rallied to have the new airport runway flight path diverted so that planes taking off and landing would follow the river instead of flying at low altitudes directly over their homes.

The difference is that in the transitive use, the direct object, here "the community", is being roused to some end, and in the intransitive use, the subject, here "the community" is rising up of its own accord.

Comment: Nice answer! I think this one makes the clearest distinction between the two different usages.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck I wanted to avoid going down the rabbit hole of trying to describe the nuanced difference between a not quite idiomatic utterance and an idiomatic one.  I took the easy way out and made up my own sentences. :-)